# Create wordforms using python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, textblob

How can I get different word forms using Python. I want to create a list like the following.

```
Work=['Work','Working','Works']
```

My code:

```
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
cleaned = re.sub(r'& ?(ld|rd)quo ?[;\]]', '\"', raw)
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(cleaned)
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
t = [stemmer.stem(t) if t in Words else t for t in tokens]
text = nltk.Text(t)
word = words(n)
Words = [stemmer.stem(e) for e in word]
find = ' '.join(str(e) for e in Words)
search_words = set(find.split(' '))
sents = ' '.join([s.lower() for s in text])
blob = TextBlob(sents.decode('ascii','ignore'))
matches = [map(str, blob.sentences[i-1:i+2])     # from prev to after next
            for i, s in enumerate(blob.sentences) # i is index, e is element
            if search_words & set(s.words)]
    #return list(itertools.chain(' '.join (str(y).replace('& rdquo','').replace('& rsquo','') for y in matches))
return list(itertools.chain(*matches))
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Don't know whether there is a thing like "reverse stemming". Your best chance might be to take a large corpus, stem it, and memorize what word was stemmed to what stem.

Comment: @pfnuesel I know how to stem words. Now i want to reverse engineer the stemmer. Need to limit the stemming to the words in the list. So i need to convert the word with the actual endings in english in various wordforms. I tried but no-go

Comment: @tobias_k Then can i limit the stemming of tokens only to words in the text. I dont want to stemm the  whole text. I am adding the code above

Comment: Also, it might be interesting to know what you need this list of word forms for. Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: Anyone has a way to do it?

Comment: How about looping through the words in the text, and for each word which also is in your word list, perform the stemming, and use sth like `groupby` to collect the ones which belong together?

Comment: @Alfe unfortunately the wordforms exist in the text.  I tried the below:t = [stemmer.stem(t) if stemmer.stem(t) in Words else t for t in tokens] still no-go

Answer (score 0):

It was a little tricky. I tried to look at the stemmed forms in the text and then mapped it with the list of words. Also i changed it to lower case since tokenizing doesn't do that and than it mapped perfectly. Below is the updated code

```
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
cleaned = re.sub(r'& ?(ld|rd)quo ?[;\]]', '\"', raw)
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(cleaned)
lower = [w.lower() for w in tokens]
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
t = [stemmer.stem(t) if t in Words else t for t in lower]
text = nltk.Text(t)
word = words(n)
Words = [stemmer.stem(e) for e in word]
find = ' '.join(str(e) for e in Words)
search_words = set(find.split(' '))
sents = ' '.join([s.lower() for s in text])
blob = TextBlob(sents.decode('ascii','ignore'))
matches = [map(str, blob.sentences[i-1:i+2])     # from prev to after next
        for i, s in enumerate(blob.sentences) # i is index, e is element
        if search_words & set(s.words)]
#return list(itertools.chain(' '.join (str(y).replace('& rdquo','').replace('& rsquo','') for y in matches))
```

return list(itertools.chain(*matches))