# How to find related words with python nltk

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I know wordnet and nltk can be used to identify synonyms e.g.

```
wordnet.synsets('fix')
['fix.n.01', 'fix.n.02', 'repair.n.01', 'fix.n.04', 'localization.n.01', 'repair.v.01', 'fasten.v.01', ... ]
```

but I want to find 'word forms' f.e. for 'fix' I would like to get a result similar to:

```
[fix, fixes, fixed, fixing, bugfix, ... ]
```

I this possible with the nltk package? I did not find something similar in the docs, but maybe I missed something as english is not my native language. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you mean with related. From what you give as the result, it seems that you want all different word forms of a word rather than syn-, hyper- and hyponyms. Could you elaborate more on what you want as a result?

Comment: Yes, I just didn't know how to call it but word forms does make sense.

Comment: That is a really difficult task in python. You would have to I'll call it "reverse stem". There is no such functionality built in nltk to my knowledge. You'd have to run through some corpus, stem all words and build your own corpus from that. You could try the following approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952690/create-wordforms-using-python
But as I said that's a lot of work...

Comment: Oh ok thanks anyways, I thought this would be a common task in natural language processing, so I thought I missed something in the docs.

Comment: Well there are tools to generate basic lemma forms out of a stem. I think you can do that with Wordnet by filtering through the lemmas of your synsets. Maybe you can  think of something with the help of these examples: http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html
But to get more abstract wordforms like "bugfix", you'd need to do as I said and even then you can't hope to get even half of the words a stem can generate. As an extreme example, if you think of a language like german, you can build theoretically endless nouns with compounds. So you see why this is a near impossible task.